# Datatables show column and hide other columns

Tags: datatables, show-hide

I use datatable library in the table, and I have this code to toggle columns to show and hide

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var column = $('#workColMainTable').DataTable().columns($(this).attr('data-column'));

            column.visible(!column.visible());
        });
    });
```

I want to show clicked column and hide other columns

my HTML

```
<div class="nav">
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">All</a>
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2">Verified</a>
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3">Completed</a>
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="4">Resulted</a>
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="5">Confirmed</a>
</div>
<table id="workColMainTable">
  <thead>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
    <th>Four</th>
    <th>Five</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Urgent</td>
      <td>Resource</td>
      <td>0123456781</td>
      <td>Clear</td>
      <td>Box</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

get column length of the datatble

```
numCols = table.columns().nodes().length;
```

after getting the column length ., do loop

This will give the column index you are clicking

```
$(this).attr('data-column')
```

```
for (let i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
    if(i==$(this).attr('data-column'))
        table.columns( [i-1] ).visible( true);
      else
      table.columns( [i-1] ).visible( false);
}
```